# how to get whole user timeline of a specific twitter user

Tags: python, json, api, twitter, tweepy

so I came up with this script to get the all of a user tweet from one twitter user

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import json

def load_api():
Consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_secret = ''
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
return tweepy.API(auth)

api = load_api()
user = 'allkpop'
tweets = api.user_timeline(id=user, count=2000)
print('Found %d tweets' % len(tweets))

tweets_text = [t.text for t in tweets]
filename = 'tweets-'+user+'.json'
json.dump(tweets_text, open(filename, 'w'))
print('Saved to file:', filename)
```

but when I run it I can only get 200 tweets per request. Is there a way to get 2000 tweets or at least more than 2000 tweets?

please help me, thank you

Comment: _Is there a way to get 2000 tweets or at least more than 2000 tweets?_ Wouldn't that information be found in the docs for tweepy?

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter API has request limits. The one you're using corresponds to the Twitter [statuses/user_timeline](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline) endpoint. The max number that you can get for this endpoint is documented as 3,200. Also note that there's a max number of requests in a 15-minute window, which might explain why you're only getting 2000, instead of the max. Here are a couple observations that might be interesting for you:

1. Documentation says that the max count is 200.
2. There's an include_rts (include retweets) parameter that might return more values. While it's part of the Twitter API, I can't see where Tweepy documents that.
3. You might try [Tweepy Cursors](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.8.0/cursor_tutorial.html) to see if that will bring back more items.
4. Because of the 15 minute limits, you might be able to pause until the next 15 minute window to continue. That said, I don't know enough about your use case to know if this is practical or not.